# Why does the 12 factor app methodology recommend preventing devs from changing the code at runtime?

Tags: 12factor

[Step 5 (Build, release, run)](https://www.12factor.net/build-release-run) of 12FA makes it impossible for devs to change code at runtime. It doesn't explain why this is good.

It makes things like adding temporary logging, or applying a quick hotfix to production code - both very feasible if the application hasn't scaled beyond a single instance yet - impossible.

Is it recommended simply to prevent devs from shooting themselves in the foot (by deploying a change that breaks the running app), or is there some other benefit I'm not seeing?

Comment: "prevent devs from shooting themselves in the foot" isn't enough?

Comment: It is. Just asking to make sure there's not some Great Truth I'm missing :D